# Access the instance from current instance

Tags: java, instance

I want to get the instance of the class, where this instance has been made, is it possible?

**Note:** Classes are not nested.

```
    class Frame {
        protected Panel p1;
        private String name;
        public Frame(String name) {
            this.name=name;
            p1=new Panel();
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

..

```
    class Panel {
        public Panel() {
            System.out.println("I was made in: "+Frame.this.getName()); 
                                    // but you can't do this
        }   
    }
```

..

```
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f1=new Frame("first"); // should print: first
        Frame f2=new Frame("second"); // should print: second
    }
```

**Note 2: I am aware of this approach:**

```
 class Frame {
        protected Panel p1;
        private String name;
        public Frame(String name) {
            this.name=name;
            p1=new Panel();
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

..

```
    class Panel {
                private Frame owner;
        public Panel(Frame owner) {
                        this.owner=owner; // DECLARING OWNER
            System.out.println("I was made in: "+owner.getName()); 

        }   
    }
```

..

```
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f1=new Frame("first"); // should print: first
        Frame f2=new Frame("second"); // should print: second
    }
```

...but this doesn't make me happy, i want somehow directly to access, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. I'm not sure if it even compiles, I can't check where I am. But this should be the general idea of what you're looking for.

```
Class A {
    B b = B.masterB;
    A() { }
    getB() { return b;}
}

Class B {
  static B masterB = new B();

    A a;
    B() {
       a=new A();
    }
    getA() { return a; }
}

class main
{

static void main(string[] args) {
  A a = new A();
  B result = a.getB();
}
```

Comment: Yes, like this, but this is the only way? I can't somehow access directly?

Comment: I don't think i need singletons. Even through If i have multiple instance of either class, the "super" instance will be unique...

Comment: Well, this implements some weird singleton... masterB will contain unknown instance...

Comment: You said "super" instance, that's what I thought I was giving you lol. I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for

Comment: I will explain in a minute, better, reload for original post

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance variable of type `B` in class `A`.  Accept a parameter of type `B` in the constructor for `A`.

In `B`'s constructor, pass `this` to the constructor for `A`.

```
class A {
    B b;
    A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        // get the instance of B so i can call do this, for example:
        b.getA();
    }
}

class B {
    A a;
    B() {
       a=new A(this);
    }
    A getA() { return a; }

}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am aware of this approach, i need something which can access directly or that thing doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can override method as follows

```
public class Frame {

    protected Panel p1;
    private String name;
    public Frame(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        p1=new Panel() {
            public String ownerName() {
                return getName();
            }
        };
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    class Panel {
        public Panel() {
            System.out.println("I was made in: "+ownerName()); 

        }

        public String ownerName() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Frame f1=new Frame("first"); 
         Frame f2=new Frame("second");
    }
}
```